# long text as String in python

Tags: python, string, text

Hey I would like to declare a String in Python which is a long text (with line breaks and paragraphs). Is this possible?
If I just copy-paste de text into quotations Python only recognizes the first line and I have to manually remove all the line breaks if I want the entire text. If this is possible would it still be possible if the text have quotations ("")?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use triple quotes :

```
mytext = """Some text
Some more text
etc...
"""
```

Comment: Note that while not commonly used, triple single quotes also work although triple-double-quotes are preferred (as long as your string doesn't contain triple-double-quotes).  Phew, that's a mouthful.

Comment: Just what I meant. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Surround your string content with """ to indicate a multi-line string.

```
>>>a = """
...this
...is
...a
...multi-line
...string
..."""
>>> a
'this\nis\na\nmulti-line\nstring\n'
```